# Is it possible to remove the first element of a datatable cell, which is a string value?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a `datatable` filled with strings.

On a column of these I want to remove the first 2 elements.

""Edit: By element i mean the first 2 characters of the string of a datacell. End of Edit""

Such thing is easy in strings, using the `remove` command. But is the same possible in a datacell?

PS: Some might answer "Why not define the string first, and then place it on the cell" but I'd rather avoid it, since my cells are defined by a series of concatenations. Here's how I'm doing it.

```
//create a list of the columns name
  List<string> listadecolunas = new List<string>();
                foreach (DataColumn coluna in DataAccess.Instance.tabelafinal5.Columns)
                {
                    listadecolunas.Add(coluna.ColumnName);

                }

 //create a concatenated string that encolsures all the following columns

 for (int i = 0; i < DataAccess.Instance.tabelafinal5.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int y = 2; y < listadecolunas.Count; y++)
                    {
                        string elemento0 = DataAccess.Instance.tabelafinal5.Rows[i][y].ToString();

                        if (elemento0 != "")
                        {

                                DataAccess.Instance.tabelafinal5.Rows[i]["Expressão"] = DataAccess.Instance.tabelafinal5.Rows[i]["Expressão"] + " + " + elemento0;
                        }
                    }

                }
```

I didn't want to fill this with detail, but since I've posted the code, in the end I will get a datacell that begins with `+` and I want to remove it, it's just that.

Edit2:
My cell looks like this
[image]

I wanna remove the first `+` :)

Comment: why not use the string.Replace function and or substring function to replace the value of the elements based on their substring then call the string.replace function or vice versa...also to better support your question so others can understand.. you should show what the string looks like and give an example of what you want the outcome to look like..?

Comment: But i would have to do that before defining the datacell, or can i do it after?

Comment: show an example of the existing cell content first ..and what you want it to look like and perhaps I can answer that question for you...

Comment: There it goes @MethodMan I've edited the question and posted what's happening. I hope it gets clear now

Comment: you could just assign the value of the data in the cell to a `var` by saying `var newValue = substring(1, length(that column data - 1)` for example since it appears to always be in the same location.. you would also want to check if the substring(0,1) = "+" do the replace..else use the current / existing value you do not want to use the replace() function since you have many `+` chars in the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a little helper like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < DataAccess.Instance.tabelafinal5.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    bool isFirst = true;
    for (int y = 2; y < listadecolunas.Count; y++)
    {
        string elemento0 = DataAccess.Instance.tabelafinal5.Rows[i][y].ToString();

        if (elemento0 != "")
        {
            if(isFirst)
            {
                isFirst = false;
                DataAccess.Instance.tabelafinal5.Rows[i]["Expressão"] = DataAccess.Instance.tabelafinal5.Rows[i]["Expressão"] + elemento0;
            }
            else
            {
                DataAccess.Instance.tabelafinal5.Rows[i]["Expressão"] = DataAccess.Instance.tabelafinal5.Rows[i]["Expressão"] + " + " + elemento0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A little more efficient with a `StringBuilder` but same concept:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < DataAccess.Instance.tabelafinal5.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    bool isFirst = true;
    sb.Clear();
    for (int y = 2; y < listadecolunas.Count; y++)
    {
        string elemento0 = DataAccess.Instance.tabelafinal5.Rows[i][y].ToString();

        if (elemento0 != "")
        {
            if(isFirst)
            {
                isFirst = false;
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(" + ")
            }
            sb.Append(elemento0);
        }
    }
    if(sb.Length > 0)
    {
    DataAccess.Instance.tabelafinal5.Rows[i]["Expressão"] = DataAccess.Instance.tabelafinal5.Rows[i]["Expressão"] + sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Now, if you even construct the Cell across different methods and you do not know what has happened before, you would set `isFirst` based on if the current value of the cell is empty or not instead of assigning `true` to it by default.